# What is this symbol called for Standard Deviation?

Tags: terminology

What is the symbol to the right called, and is it available in Latex or MathJax?

I found it at the bottom of [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/statistics/statistics_standard_deviation.php), the other symbols have pronunciations or are Greek letters, but this one does not.

[image: Sample standard deviation]

Comment: And yeah I'm new here.

Comment: Do you mean the letter s? It's common to use Greek letters for parameters ($\mu$, $\sigma$) and their Latin counterparts for their estimates ($m$, $s$). Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: This is a small Latin "s" ("ess").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $\TeX$, many browsers (Firefox, Chrome) will show it to you if the formulas are formatted in MathJax (most popular). When you right-click on the symbol there is the menu *Show Math As > TeX Commands*. In the case of the symbol, it is just a lower case "s" letter.

As described on the page, it is used to denote "sample standard deviation". Latin letters are commonly used for sample statistics, while Greek ones are used for population parameters, so the population mean is $\mu$ and the population standard deviation is $\sigma$, while sample counterparts are $\bar x$ and $s$, etc. Keep in mind that those are only conventions: the symbols are not reserved so you can see other symbols used there instead as well.